# React Native - Modifying TextInput after function call

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to make a form that after hitting enter will move automatically to the following parameter. I figured out a way of doing it but will take me literally hundreds of lines of code. I think there must be an easier way. I basically have two questions:

1. How to add a counter to the XInput2 part.
2. How to correctly add a ref. My current code is giving: undefined is not an Object this5.refs.XInput.focus() is not defined.

So this is the code for rendering my TextInput fields.

```
renderTextField(options) {
    return (
        <TextInput
            style={styles.textfield}
            onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ [options.name]: value})}
            onSubmitEditing={(event) => { 
            this.refs.XInput.focus(); 
            }}
            placeholder={options.label}
            value={this.state[options.name]}
            keyboardType={options.keyboard || 'default'}
        />
    );
}
```

And this would be the code I'm using for calling it.

```
{this.renderTextField({ name: 'cacao21', label: 'Fermented Beans', ref="XInput1"})}
{this.renderTextField({ name: 'cacao22', label: 'Partially Fermented Beans', ref="XInput2"})}
```

Please take a look at the XInput. I think that the best way would be using kind of a counter for the XInput value and manually modify it. How can I add a counter for this value or is there a better way?

```
onSubmitEditing={(event) => { 
                this.refs.XInput.focus(); 
                }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String refs are being deprecated and should be avoided. Don't worry, the recommended way will save you some headache in the long run and is quiet simple to understand.

So essentially I fixed the ref to actually be defined in the TextInput and instead of worrying about complicated counter system I simplify it with a `next` option that will be the name of the next field on submit.

This should get you started:

```
renderTextField = (options) => {
  return (
    <TextInput
      ref={(tInput) => { this.refs[options.name] = tInput; }}
      style={{ height: 25 }}
      onChangeText={(value) => this.setState({ [options.name]: value })}
      onSubmitEditing={() => {
        if (options.next) {
          this.refs[options.next].focus();
        }
      }}
      placeholder={options.label}
      value={this.state[options.name]}
      keyboardType={options.keyboard || 'default'}
    />
  );
};
```

The other bit:

```
{renderTextField({ name: 'cacao21', label: 'Fermented Beans', next: 'cacao22' })}
{renderTextField({ name: 'cacao22', label: 'Partially Fermented Beans', next: 'cacao23' })}
{renderTextField({ name: 'cacao23', label: 'End of the Bean Line' })}
```